# Steps to listen to a "connection less UDP Multicast" with C++ and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, multicast

I have to listen to a "Connection-less UDP Multicast". I have a the server's IP and port. I do not have any other information. How do I accomplish this ?

I did some searching and found some hints [like](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/134540-difference-between-multicast-broadcast.html) this:

1. Server uses recvfrom() to listen on the broadcast IP.
2. The client sends 1 packet to query the server using sendto() on the broadcast IP.
3. The server takes the client's IP and Port from the return address in recvfrom()
4. The server responds from it's own IP and port directly to the client.
5. The client takes the server's IP and Port from the return address in recvfrom()
6. Since they now have each other's "direct line" normal communications can begin

I also read [this](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Pocket+pc+network+programming/Chapter+1.+Winsock/Connectionless+UDP+Sockets/) helpful article. But the article is for `winsockets`. I know that is not supposed to make a lot of difference to the theory, I am still quite confused when it comes to the implementation. For example, you will see that in many places they suggest that one must call `sendto()` and then use the `sockaddr` returned for `recvfrom`. However I dont understand why this is suggested. Don't we already know the the address and port ? Is it just to avoid filling the struct by hand or is it about the other parameters of `sockaddr`?

Also, in the same article they use the following flag `IPPROTO_UDP` in call to socket:

```
SOCKET sUDPSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

Does the same apply for linux as well? Where can I find such information?

I am looking for a solid reference on this problem. I googled quite a bit, but could not find any authoritative article or blog to do it on Linux.

Comment: IP broadcast is not the same as multicast.  Which do you want?

Comment: I'm not sure what did you mean by connection-less but I've found this: http://www.tenouk.com/Module41c.html

Comment: @drum Connection-less means I do not have to subscribe to any multicast group.

Comment: @user3553031 I want a udp connection less multicast.

Comment: @drum I had gone through the link you posted. It is not for a connection less communication.

Comment: @Wildling: In that case, your reference about broadcast won't help, because that's something different.

Comment: @user3553031 yeah, hence this question. I cannot seem to find a resource addressing my concerns.

Comment: @Wildling The thing is that UDP is, by nature, connection-less. So as long as you are creating a UDP server-client, it should work.

Comment: @Wildling The inverse of connection-less, in this case, would be TCP. A connection pretty much means to maintain a state.

Comment: @drum yeah, but how do I implement an inverse-tcp ? There is a particular method to be followed here. Certain flags have to be used. Need information about that.

Comment: @Wildling You implement it according to the link I gave you. As long as you use SOCK_DGRAM, it should be using UDP, thus connection-less.

Comment: Multicast *is* about joining groups. What's your objection to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said

> I have to listen to a Connection-less UDP Multicast

In your comment you clarified the meaning of your question:

> Connection-less means I do not have to subscribe to any multicast group

Well, that isn't possible.  The only way for your computer to receive multicast traffic is for your router to forward it to you, and the router only does that when a multicast subscription exists.  Consider the alternative: every router should forward multicast packets even when there is no subscription?  But then all multicast packets would be flooded through the whole network, which would exceed the available bandwidth of many links, effectively creating a denial of service attack.

If you just want auto-discovery on the local network, you need a broadcast, not multicast.  Broadcast is done with the same functions as unicast UDP, and no connection is needed.  However, you do have to enable the `SO_BROADCAST` option using `setsockopt`.

Comment: You were right. I had to call `setsockopt` with `IPPROTO_IP` and `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` flags along with the multicast group address to receive the data